# Solr autocomplete does not work for Product Variations

Tags: commerce, search, 9

I am trying to create a sitewide search using Solr. For this, I indexed Product Variations and Content entities as Rendered HTML Output. When I try to search for a content entity, the autocomplete works and gives me the results, but it fails to give the results for Product Variations. The search itself works both for Content and Commerce entities. I am using Search API Solr with version 4.2 and Search API Autocomplete with version 1.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search API autocomplete requires a canonical links for entities to build suggestions list. Even if there is a result from index server, if it can't build a link, this result will be ignored. In your case, product variation simply doesn't have a canonical link, see https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce/-/blob/8.x-2.x/modules/product/src/Entity/ProductVariation.php#L79-90
Adding a canonical link will fix the issue. I have found a patch here https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/3025860#comment-14597209

Comment: Search API autocomplete _can_ be configured so that the selections are simply search keywords, not direct links to the entities. It depends on which suggester is used.